# ActiveState log files proliferate in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, activestate

Whenever I run VS Code, my directory fills with dozens of files with error messages, with names like "state-99999.log, and contents like the following.  I have no idea where these are from (I don't use activeState) and how to get rid of them:

```
[ERROR Jun  4 14:42:19.225202200, defaults.go:149] Could not load configuration: Failed to load configuration.

Stacktrace: D:/a/cli/cli/internal/logging/logging.go:github.com/ActiveState/cli/internal/logging.Error:258
D:/a/cli/cli/internal/logging/defaults.go:github.com/ActiveState/cli/internal/logging.init.0:149
C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/go/1.15.11/x64/src/runtime/proc.go:runtime.doInit:5652
C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/go/1.15.11/x64/src/runtime/proc.go:runtime.doInit:5647
C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/go/1.15.11/x64/src/runtime/proc.go:runtime.doInit:5647
C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/go/1.15.11/x64/src/runtime/proc.go:runtime.main:191
C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/go/1.15.11/x64/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:runtime.goexit:1374

[DEBUG Jun  4 14:42:19.227203700, defaults.go:178] Args: [C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\ActiveState\bin\state.exe show --output editor]
[DEBUG Jun  4 14:42:19.229204500, locale.go:34] Init
```

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveState extension for VS Code is the source of the problem.  Uninstalling the extension in VS Code prevents it from generating the nuisance log files.